# Mongoose update is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My question here is why isn't the `watchlistSchema.update(function (error) { { $push: { watchlist: req.body.stockAdded } }});` line updating the existing schema for the watchlist attribute? When I use this update nothing happens and it returns null. When I change it to watchlistSchema.save it work but it creates and entirely different document. I would like to basically check for the user and watchlist and if they both exist together I would like to push a string into the watchlist array. I am very new to mongoose so it is a bit confusing.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

var watchlistSchema = new Schema({
    watchlist: [{ }],
    user: String
});

var Watchlist = mongoose.model('Watchlist', watchlistSchema, "watchlist");    

app.post('/watchlistPost', function (req, res) {

var watchlistSchema = Watchlist({
    'watchlist': req.body.stockAdded,
    'user': req.user.username
});

Watchlist.findOne({
    $and: [{
        'watchlist': req.body.stockAdded,
    }, {
        'user': req.user.username
    }]
}, function (err, list) {
    if (list) {
        res.status(200).send({ "success": "Updated Successfully", "status": 200 });
    } else {
        if (req.user) {
            watchlistSchema.update(function (error) {
                { $push: { watchlist: req.body.stockAdded } }
            });
        } else {

        }
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) statement needs to contain the "find" query. So it can appy the update condition to all documents matching the specified query.

change your code to something like:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;    

var watchlistSchema = new Schema({
    watchlist: [{ }],
    user: String
});

var Watchlist = mongoose.model('Watchlist', watchlistSchema, "watchlist");    

app.post('/watchlistPost', function (req, res) {

var watchlistSchema = Watchlist({
    'watchlist': req.body.stockAdded,
    'user': req.user.username
});

var query = {
    $and: [{
        'watchlist': req.body.stockAdded,
    }, {
        'user': req.user.username
    }]};

Watchlist.update(query, { $push: { watchlist: req.body.stockAdded } }, ==your callback to check stuff==);
```